# How to get a transparent region from UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, transparency

I develop a client app.
My question is: under the iPhone platform, how do I get a transparent region from UIImage?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [image masking](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html). Try this -

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
const float colorMasking[6] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image.CGImage, colorMasking)];
```

Answer (score 0):

create a mask layer to control the transparent region of the image.

see apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/LayerVisProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006074-SW21